# Should we actively recruit in discussions on Area51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, meta-tags, scope

Over on Area51's discuss section, I just [encountered this thread](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/please-vote-for-example-questions-and-invite-friends-were-very-close), which is actively recruiting on its prop page. However, due to the new system the question spills over. Is recruiting on-topic or should it be discouraged? If on topic, should we tag as [recruitment](/questions/tagged/recruitment), or would this be a meta-tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Area 51 discussions weren't really created for users to recruit followers or promote someone's proposal to the participants. The forum was provided to discuss *specific* problems with proposals. Nobody wants to wade through pages and pages of *"hey, come vote on my stuff"* posts to see if there are any  *real* issues needing attention.

You can imagine what a mess this site (meta.stackoverflow) would be if Stack Overflow users came in here to recruit users to answer their questions and vote-up their posts. The same general analogy applies to the Area 51 discussions.

The basic commenting feature will soon be restored to Area 51 proposals, but even that is going to be somewhat limited in its usage. To extend the Stack Overflow analogy, you expect *"Please vote up my answer"* comments to be somewhat frowned upon. The same ideas of *appropriate use* apply to Area 51.

Comment: I have no real opinion on it, but would tagging those questions, thus making it so they can be filtered out, be a workable situation?  Or should they just be closed?

Comment: @mfg: They should just be close. Tagging off topic content just encourages more of that type of post.

Answer (score 2):

Since we have rid ourselves of the comments, I have used discussions to get the followers of proposals moving, especially on proposals that are reasonably close to going into the commitment stage.

If we allow such messages, though, then the questions become cluttered on https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/ which is not good.

What can we do on the proposal to contact and reach followers, as a call to action, that won't clutter up the general discussion area?